# Are there certain files I should not be including in a barrel file in Angular 2 and/or does the order of imports matter?

Tags: angularjs, angular, import, dependency-injection, export

I have a feature folder with an `index.ts` that looks like this:

```
export * from './grouping.model'
export * from './grouping.routing';
export * from './group.component';
export * from './supergroup.component';
export * from './grouping-container.component';
export * from './grouping.service';
export * from './grouping.module';
```

Initially I was getting this error: `Can't resolve all parameters for SupergroupComponent: (?, ActivatedRoute)`. I then changed the order in which these files were exported and am getting a different issue (`Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'GroupingModule'`).

If I remove the `.service` file from this barrel file and import it on a separate line in my component, everything works. I can't seem to find anything that talks about this issue, what should or shouldn't be included in barrel files or whether the order in which these files are exported matters.

I would assume that the order does indeed matter, but I've ordered my imports so that I import the lowest level building blocks and move up, but I still get the `unresolved parameters` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a pretty simple fix. The order of exports in your barrel file does matter. Start at the lowest level and work your way up and that'll take care of the issue.

Comment: I think you had a case of circular dependency. Barrel files are prone to CD. I can't cite any particular source but it pops up here and there in build tool/bundler issues.